# How can I append the creation date to all files in a folder and the subfolders in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a small script that can successfully copy all the files from folders and subfolders and append the creation time, but the files in the subfolders do not have the creation time appended to their names.

How can I append the creation date to all files in a folder and the subfolders?

My current script is:

```
$path = "C:\test1"
$destination = "C:\test2"

Get-ChildItem -path $path | ForEach-Object{
        $newname = $_.CreationTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + $_.BaseName +$_.Extension
        (Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $_.FullName -Destination ( Join-Path  $destination $newname)) 
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `-Recurse` flag from `Copy-Item` and put it on the `Get-ChildItem` line. I can't test this solution right now but your initial problem is that you are doing your new name logic from the result of a superficial `Get-ChildItem` which never go more than 1 layer. So, instead of a superficial Get-ChildItem and a recursive Copy-Item, you need to do a recursive `Get-ChildItem` and superficial copy-item. I think that should work, although I am unsure what is the behavior of copy-item without recurse for not empty folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close, but the `-Recurse` switch should have been on `Get-ChildItem` and within the loop you need to make sure the destination subfolder paths exist.

Try

```
$source      = "C:\test1"
$destination = "C:\test2"

Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # create the new target folderpath for the copy
    $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($source.Length)
    # make sure the target path exists, if not create it
    $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $targetPath -Force
    # create a new filename with CreationDate prefixed
    $newName = '{0:yyy-MM-dd}{1}{2}' -f $_.CreationTime, $_.BaseName, $_.Extension
    # copy the file
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination (Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath $newname) -Force
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While you could create your own recursive method to copy files and rename them as you go, it would be easier to use `Copy-Item` recursively and rename the files and folders afterwards:

```
$Source = "src"
$Destination = "dst"

Copy-Item -Recurse $Source $Destination

foreach ($Item in (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File $Destination)) {
    Rename-Item $Item ($Item.Name + "-" + $Item.CreationTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
}
```